# Creating a valid settings bundle plist for child pane

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to develop my first app and I'm implementing a settings bundle with a child pane. I am also using IASK. Whenever I try to open my settings in the Settings app it simply does not work and when I try to open it in my IASK child pane, the app crashes leaving this error message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'invalid settings plist'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 802.6.1 - Device: iPhone 12 (62C8FF00-D6FE-4526-8351-7F5B0AEEC9BA) - Runtime: iOS 15.5 (19F70) - DeviceType: iPhone 12
```

Currently this is what my plist looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
    <string>childPaneStrings</string>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Name</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>name_preference</string>
            <key>AutocorrectionType</key>
            <string>No</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've checked it over multiple times now and I can't find anything wrong with the plist.

Sorry if my post is missing anything. This is my first question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of trying to figure out what was going on, I finally found the issue. Even though Xcode was showing that my plist file was within my settings bundle, a quick look with finder showed me that it wasn't actually there. I manually put the plist file into my settings bundle through finder and now it works.